# Parsing CSV files, and writing them into another CSV format

Tags: python, csv

The format of my import CSV fetched using urllib2 and put into folders are like so:

```
number,season,episode,production code,airdate,title,special?,tvrage
1,1,1,"101",24/Sep/07,"Pilot",n,"http://www.tvrage.com/Chuck/episodes/579282"
```

Now I am successfully converting that into SQL statments as well as another CSV file that can be inserted into my database. Into a format like so:

```
,1,1,1,"Pilot",'2006-10-11',,,,,1,2011-12-23 15:52:49,2011-12-23 15:52:49,1,1
```

Using the following code

```
csv = """,%s,%s,%s,%s,%r,,,,,1,2011-12-23 15:52:49,2011-12-23 15:52:49,1,1""" % (showid, line[1],line[2], line[5], date(line[4]))
    print>>final, csv
```

EDIT -

I have changed from string formatting to this:

```
csv = ','+showid+','+line[1]+','+line[2]+','+line[5]+','+date(line[4])+',,,,,1,2011-12-23 15:52:49,2011-12-23 15:52:49,1,1'
```

Its not much better, and I am still having trouble with some files being skipped on the parse. Not sure if its me or the CSV module.

Problem is its going through some files perfectly fine. Some CSV files it just skips, and for some I just get errors like IndexError: list index out of range

If anyone has experience with CSV files and getting them to parse correctly I would really appreciate the help.

Here is the Full Source Code:
http://cl.ly/2W472g303D1p0J3S2o46

dsimport.py - http://pastie.org/3076663
CSVFileHandler.py - http://pastie.org/3076667

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)? If so, why aren't you using it?

Comment: Yep I am  using the CSV module, just having some strange anomalies

Comment: You're obviously *not* using the csv module if you're pasting a csv "string" together manually. Or attempting to.

Comment: I have included the source code, it is just 2 files im using.
I am using the CSV module, that is just for taking the imports and changing some values around.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what are all the errors, but here are a few tips:

1. processFile(line), `line` is a bit of a bad name as it isn't a string line, it's a `row` or list of elements. That's what confused Tim and me as well at first sight.
2. You should verify that `line` has at least 6 elements as your script requires.
3. You can use the `join` method which is awesome.

Here's a small refactoring:

```
def processFile(row):
    if len(row) < 6:
        #raise Exception('too few columns')
        # maybe it's better to just ignore bad rows in your case
        return
    items = [
        '',
        showid,
        row[1],
        row[2],
        row[5],
        date(row[4]),
        ]
    res = ','.join(items)
    res += ',,,,,1,2011-12-23 15:52:49,2011-12-23 15:52:49,1,1'
    print res
    print>>final, res

handler = CSVFileHandler('/Users/tharshan/WebRoot/stv/export/csv/%s-save.csv' % name)
try:
    handler.process(processFile, name)    
except Exception, e:
    print 'Failed processing and skipping %s because of: %s' % (name, e)

final.close()
```

Comment: Thank you, those are some very nice tips for error catching. However, I am still running into the problem of where a CSV file has been downloaded and should be parsed and printed to the new file however its just being skipped. The lines from that file are not being printed to the console. I am just stumped, I got no idea why.

Comment: Also it does not make any sense that these CSV files would have different col numbers because they are all exported in the same format from this site.
Example: http://epguides.com/common/exportToCSV.asp?rage=20720

Comment: If exceptions are thrown, then please do list them. If files are just "skipped" then maybe you should try and print every time you enter main() whatever filename should be handled and see if that function is indeed called as many times as you planned. If `main()` is called enough times then. hmmm. I just noticed something. You really should close that file `final` every time you finish appending to it (at the end of `main`).

Comment: Thanks, ive added the close at the end just for good measure. I am unsure of how to check if the main is called enough times, does you mean just by a simple counter perhaps? and see if it matched the array size?

Ive done what you suggested, and have a look at these print outs:
Very strange indeed, I dont get how some of these rows are possible.I think the parser is messing up somehow
http://pastie.org/3076993

Comment: It seems a lot of csv files are skipped because somewhere in them they had too few columns. Maybe you should just skip the rows that have too few columns. I updated my solution for that.

Comment: The problem is though - its not a bad case and the rows are not lower than the if. The files that is giving the error - Ive checked em all. They all have the exam patter and rows and this is why I know that an error should not be happening.

Comment: Okay so the problem is titles that have a comma in them, and the orginal csv file they are not escaped. Is there any way I can get around this? For example:
`['73', '4', '15', '"415"', '18/Mar/10', '"Don Geiss', ' America and Hope"', 'n', '"http://www.tvrage.com/30_Rock/episodes/1064899212"']`
The title is: Don Geiss, America and Hope.
As you can see its being split into two items, because of the comma.

Comment: Is there any way to know this from the csv files? When you use the csv module to write csv files it allows commas because those cells would be encapsulated in double quotes (eg "Don Geiss, America and Hope").

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind all fixed. In the end I just used the excel dialect, and did the output csv with pipe lines. Either way it was quite fiddly and honestly feel like i got it to work with sheer luck.

Thanks for all the help.